# Is it possible to turn off dependence of search terms (operator) order in Google search?

Tags: google-search

I used 4 search terms in a Google search in different order (no search operator at all, only terms) and get 220000 vs. 250000 results and different sites in top 30 search results.

It's not tragic, but is there a way to turn off this dependence of search term order? Also, can someone explain how this works currently at all? Does this order also play a role when the search terms are combined with operators? If I do a search using  `inurl:term` and `intitle:term`, is the first operator weigthed stronger than the 2nd, 3rd,...? I use them nearly always, especially with a specified time frame (`2011..2012`), so this would be most interesting to me.